# Cannot read "target" property when passing value from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, event-handling

In my project `student` is child component of the parent `app` component.

The `student` component `template` has an input element as below:

```
<input type='text' #inputbox (keyup)='onkeyUp(inputbox.value)'>
```

The `student` component has defined `onkeyUp` event handler as below:

```
  @Component({
  outputs: ['childevent']
  ... 
  childevent = new EventEmitter();
  onkeyUp(value: any) {
  this.childevent.emit(value);
  }
```

The parent `app` component looks as below:

```
...
<label>Value of Child Component: </label> {{Cdata.target.value}}
<app-student (childevent)='Cdata=$event'></app-student>
```

Here, `{{Cdata.target.value}}` is throwing an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
```

As per my understanding, `$event` has the entire `childevent` payload which is passed to the `Cdata` event handler. And, `event.target.value` returns the current contents of `childevent`

Please let me know if I have correct understanding.
I am referring to [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/user-input)

I have tried to use `optional chaining`

```
<label>Value of Child Component: </label> {{Cdata?.target.value}}
```

But still getting an error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your app `template`, `Cdata` does not yet exist when the template is rendered for the first time. You can solve this by changing the code as follows:

```
<label>Value of Child Component: </label> {{ Cdata ? Cdata.target.value : 'missing' }}
```

Comment: I have tried to use `optional chaining` `<label>Value of Child Component: </label> {{Cdata?.target.value}}` but still getting an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the definition of the `EventEmitter`, you can [check](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-paper-pnd5n?file=/src/app/parent/parent.component.ts):

```
@Output() childevent = new EventEmitter();
```